# PySpark - Window Function with Filter

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe:

| id | instance | price | important |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 1 | 5 | 0 |
| a1 | 2 | 8 | 1 |
| a1 | 3 | 9 | 0 |
| a1 | 4 | 14 | 1 |
| a1 | 5 | 9 | 0 |
| b2 | 1 | 7 | 0 |
| b2 | 2 | 14 | 1 |
| b2 | 3 | 8 | 0 |
| b2 | 4 | 22 | 1 |
| b2 | 5 | 6 | 0 |

I want to be able to create 2 new columns in such a way that the output looks like this:

| id | instance | price | important | avg_price_til_next_Y | avg_price_previous |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 1 | 5 | 0 | null | null |
| a1 | 2 | 8 | Y | 9 | 5 |
| a1 | 3 | 9 | 0 | null | 6.5 |
| a1 | 4 | 14 | Y | 0 | 7.3333 |
| a1 | 5 | 9 | 0 | null | 9 |
| b2 | 1 | 7 | 0 | null | null |
| b2 | 2 | 14 | Y | 8 | 7 |
| b2 | 3 | 8 | 0 | null | 10.5 |
| b2 | 4 | 22 | Y | 0 | 9.6667 |
| b2 | 5 | 6 | 0 | null | 12.75 |

The avg_price_previous column is basically the average of all the previous instances' prices for the same id. Its value is null for the first instance.

The avg_price_til_next_Y column is basically the average price incurred between two instances marked as 'Y' in the important column for the same id. Its value is null for instances where the important column is not equal to 'Y'.

How can I achieve this using pyspark?

Comment: Could you share your code so far?  and why `avg_price_til_next_Y` for 4th and 9th rows are 0?

Comment: because they're the latest instance that has a 'Y' value for the id group